# ffmpeg Undefined referance to several swr functions

Tags: c++, cmake, ffmpeg, makefile, linker

I'm trying to staticly link ffmpeg to my project, i downloaded the ffmpeg source files from a github repo because it had pre writen cmake files, which i needed for this exact problem but it changed nothing (https://github.com/Pawday/ffmpeg-cmake). I edited the file a little and posted it below, and added them to lib/ffmpeg in my project directory. I first ran ./configure, then ran make, then make install like the install guide suggested. Then i ran cmake . followed by make. It compiled just fine and i ran a test without any errors:

```
extern "C"{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "provide a filename" << std::endl;
        return -1;
        AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    }
}
```

I was following the examples that ffmpeg provides, so i added this:

```
const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
```

But now i have this huge error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function 

`opus_decode_subpacket':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:346: undefined reference to `swr_is_initialized'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_frame':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:188: undefined reference to `swr_is_initialized'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_init_resample':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:136: undefined reference to `swr_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:142: undefined reference to `swr_convert'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_frame':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:202: undefined reference to `swr_convert'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_flush_resample':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:90: undefined reference to `swr_convert'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_subpacket':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:379: undefined reference to `swr_close'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:346: undefined reference to `swr_is_initialized'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_flush':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:582: undefined reference to `swr_close'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_close':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:607: undefined reference to `swr_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(opusdec.o): in function `opus_decode_init':
/home/t/Desktop/Code/lib/ffmpeg/libavcodec/opusdec.c:660: undefined reference to `swr_alloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Interview.dir/build.make:122: bin/Interview] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:420: CMakeFiles/Interview.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I find some questions with similar issues to no avail:

[FFmpeg seems to be version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932247/ffmpeg-seems-to-be-version-conflict)
[Linking libavcodec and libavformat: Undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366433/linking-libavcodec-and-libavformat-undefined-references)

NOTE: previously i tried downloading ffmpeg with home-brew and pkg-config maybe that is causing an error, but my guess is my cmake file is faulty.

project/CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(Interview C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${dir}/bin )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lswresample")

add_subdirectory(lib/ffmpeg)

add_definitions(-DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)

list(APPEND SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/vipch.h
    src/VideoDecoder.cpp
    src/VideoDecoder.h
    src/Application.cpp
    src/Application.h
    #src/OpenGLRenderer.cpp
    #src/OpenGLRenderer.h
    #src/Layer.h
    #src/Layer.cpp
)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(Interview src/main.cpp src/Application.cpp src/Application.h ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(Interview PRIVATE Threads::Threads)

if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-framework OpenGL"
    )

    configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist
    )

    set_target_properties(Interview PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist
    )

elseif(WIN32)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-lglu32 -lopengl32"
    )
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-std=gnu99 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mwindows")

endif()

list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
"-lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lz -lva -lswresample"
)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

#target_link_libraries(Interview ${CORELIBS})


target_include_directories(Interview PRIVATE 
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(Interview PRIVATE 
    ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY} 
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
)
```

NOTE: i previously had a really similar error with pthread but with some fixes to cmake and installing pthread i fixed it.

project/lib/ffmpeg/CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(FFMPEG C CXX)

add_library(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE)

#TODO:[cmake] COMMON DEFINES (config.h)
# create list with all that and then pick required from that list in each target
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION="")
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE FFMPEG_DATADIR="")
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE AVCONV_DATADIR="")
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE FFMPEG_LICENSE="")

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CC_IDENT="")

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_THREADS=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_PTHREADS=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_W32THREADS=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_OS2THREADS=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_ISNAN=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMXEXT=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMX2=HAVE_MMXEXT)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMX2=HAVE_MMXEXT)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMX_INLINE=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMX=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_ALTIVEC=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MMXEXT_INLINE=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_NEON=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_AMD3DNOW_INLINE=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_X86ASM=0)
if(WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MKSTEMP=0)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_MKSTEMP=1)
endif()


#TODO:[cmake] detect each function and set to 0 if missing (they are in math.h)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_CBRT=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_CBRTF=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_COPYSIGN=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_ERF=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_HYPOT=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_RINT=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_LRINT=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_LRINTF=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_ROUND=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_ROUNDF=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_TRUNC=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_TRUNCF=1)


target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ffmpeg_compat)

include (TestBigEndian)
TEST_BIG_ENDIAN(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
if(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
    target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_BIGENDIAN=1)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE HAVE_BIGENDIAN=0)
endif()

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE av_restrict=)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_THIS_YEAR=2021)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_MEMORY_POISONING=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_FRAME_THREAD_ENCODER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_MEMORY_POISONING=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_GRAY=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_ERROR_RESILIENCE=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_MPEGVIDEODEC=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_SMALL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_D3D11VA_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_DXVA2_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_NVDEC_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_VAAPI_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_VIDEOTOOLBOX_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_VDPAU_HWACCEL=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_NETWORK=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_XVMC=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_FORMAT_FILTER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_PNG_DECODER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_APNG_DECODER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_INFLATE_WRAPPER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_DEFLATE_WRAPPER=1)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_AVUTIL=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_AVCODEC=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_AVFORMAT=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_AVDEVICE=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_SWSCALE=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_SWRESAMPLE=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_POSTPROC=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_AVFILTER=1)



#CONFIG MUXERS
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_H264_MUXER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE2_MUXER=1)

#CONFIG DEMUXERS
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE2_DEMUXER=1)

# look at the end of libavformat/img2dec.c file
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_BMP_PIPE_DEMUXER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_CRI_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_DDS_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_DPX_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_EXR_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_GEM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_GIF_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_J2K_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_JPEG_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_JPEGLS_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PAM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PBM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PCX_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PGM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PGMYUV_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PGX_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PHOTOCD_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PICTOR_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PNG_PIPE_DEMUXER=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PPM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_PSD_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_QDRAW_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_SGI_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_SUNRAST_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_SVG_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_TIFF_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_WEBP_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_XBM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_XPM_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_IMAGE_XWD_PIPE_DEMUXER=0)


#CONFIG PROTOCOLS
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_FILE_PROTOCOL=1)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_PIPE_PROTOCOL=1)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_ZLIB=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE CONFIG_SWSCALE_ALPHA=0)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_X86_32=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_X86_64=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_AARCH64=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_ARM=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_PPC=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_X86=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_MIPS=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_ALPHA=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_LOONGARCH=0)
target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ARCH_LOONGARCH64=0)

target_compile_definitions(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE SWS_MAX_FILTER_SIZE=256)

#_________________________WARNINGS__________________________________________
#TODO[cmake]: set it for all targets individually or remove for WARNING HELL
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
    add_compile_options("-w")
endif()

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    add_compile_options("-w")
endif()

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0092 NEW) #cmake disable std MSVC warnings in CMAKE_C_FLAGS
    #CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C var in windows contains only /showIncludes and produce include tree
    set(CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_C "") #erase it
    add_compile_options("/w")
endif()

file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/config.h "//cmake config will define all that")
target_include_directories(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)

#TODO[cmake]: resolve config_components.h
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/config_components.h "//")
target_include_directories(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(compat)
add_subdirectory(libavutil)
add_subdirectory(libavcodec)
add_subdirectory(libavformat)
add_subdirectory(libavdevice)
add_subdirectory(libavfilter)
add_subdirectory(libswresample)
add_subdirectory(libswscale)
add_subdirectory(libpostproc)

add_subdirectory(fftools)

add_subdirectory(doc/examples)


find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

if(APPLE)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-framework OpenGL"
    )

    configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist
    )

    set_target_properties(FFMPEG PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist
    )

elseif(WIN32)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-lglu32 -lopengl32"
    )
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-std=gnu99 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mwindows")
else()
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
        "-lGL -lGLU -lX11"
    )
endif()


#target_link_libraries(Interview ${CORELIBS})

set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lswresample")

list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS
"-lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lz -lva -lswresample"
)

target_include_directories(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_config INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} 
    ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY} 
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Ubuntu 22.04, cmake 3.16.3, ffmpeg version git-2022-05-20-cb47f66

Comment: It is incorrect to add `-lswresample` option to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable: this variable is for compiler, not for the linker. In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, apparently i needed to add: find_path(SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIR libswresample/swresample.h)
find_library(SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARY swresample) it was not there on the answer i found. I also removed -lswresample, thank you!